# jQuery Superfish menu hover OR toggle depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, superfish

I'm developing a responsive menu and would like the menu to display on hover when the screen size is greater than 767px and to open on toggle when the screen size is smaller than 767px.

Is there a way to change the default setting for eventType based on screen size? i.e. is there a media query that could be inserted into the code somehow?

I am using Karl Swedberg's version of Superfish at Github:

https://gist.github.com/917446

Answer (score 2):

Check the screen size:

```
var $width = $(window).width();
```

Then test on load:

```
$(function(){
    var $width = $(window).width();

    if($width > 767){
        // do hover
    } else {
        // do toggle
    }
});
```

Or you could stick it in an external function, because you'll need to call it on window resize:

```
function checkWidth($width){
    if($width > 767){
        // do hover
    } else {
        // do toggle
    }
}

$(function(){
    checkWidth($(window).width());
});

$(window).on('resize',function(){
    checkWidth($(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statements to check the size of screen and bind events accordingly. You can use `.bind()` for it. See the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using some code I found, but it doesn't work, can you provide an actual example?

Answer (score 0):

Another option you might like to consider is using Superfish v1.5.9 which automatically uses taps to open submenus on touch devices, while simultaneously supporting mouse hovers and keyboard navigation.